# Problem with typesetting fancyhdr with chapters containing no sections

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing my thesis report and I use the current section in `\uppercase` to be set as `\lhead` on every page (one sided printing). The current chapter is not used for the headers.

I have one chapter with no sections which runs over two pages where I would like the current chapter name to be the `\lhead` in `\uppercase`. Latex typesets the current chapter on the second page of the chapter correctly but in small case. **How can I correct the chapter name here to uppercase?**

Here is some code which reproduces the phenomenon. So I would like the header on page 4 to read "***2. DEVELOPMENT STATUS***". I have read the fancyhdr package documentation but found it confusing to understand how the marks are generated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{\thechapter. \ #1}}
\lhead{\uppercase{\slshape \rightmark}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext[2]
    \section{Goals}
    \blindtext[2]
    \section{Approach}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{Development Status}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Welcome, very good example. Well done. `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. \ #1}}}`

Comment: That worked, awesome! thanks a lot @Johnannes_B :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\MakeUppercase`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{}{\thechapter. \ #1}}
\lhead{\MakeUppercase{\slshape \rightmark}}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext[2]
    \section{Goals}
    \blindtext[2]
    \section{Approach}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{Development Status}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

I also added the required setting to `\headheight`.

[image]

Comment: Well I used `\uppercase` instead of `\MakeUpperCase`. Latex does not compile with the latter. The solution offered by Johannes_B however seems to work. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Addiboy You should *never* use `\uppercase` in a LaTeX document. My solution works as advertised.

Comment: Oh ok :) I am going to retry it in that case. Pardon me but I am a novice when it comes to Latex. Why am I not supposed to use `\uppercase`?

Comment: And btw, I am sorry. Yes you are right....your solution works equally well :)

Comment: @Addiboy Because it is not LaTeX.